# Missing "that" - Why is this sentence technically/grammatically wrong?

Tags: grammar, terminology

This sentence is the first line of a book I just started reading. Authorial choices aside, as a native speaker of English, it FEELS wrong:

"The fact that it was my forty-sixth birthday should have been my first clue that day was going to suck."

I believe that there is either a missing "that" ("should have been my first clue that that day was going to suck") OR a missing "the" ("should have been my first clue that the day was going to suck").

Can someone share with me the technical grammatical rules/terms to look up to learn why this FEELS wrong to my ear?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The sentence isn't wrong.

Comment: Thank you, @HotLicks! Are all three constructions (that that day, that day, and that the day) equally correct? None are better than any others?

Comment: Understand that "that" has 4-5 distinctly different meanings.

Comment: _... my first clue that that day ..._ is just as good as _... my first clue that day ..._. The first _that_ is a complementizer and can be deleted; the second _that_ modifies _day_ and can't be deleted.

Comment: A semicolon to the rescue! *The fact that it was my forty-sixth birthday should have been my first clue; that day was going to suck*. This is why we have them, to break up the rhythm of the piece. Call the author and tell him we have solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. The fact that it was my forty-sixth birthday should have been my first clue that day was going to suck.

This is, strictly speaking, correct; the "that" here is acting as a determiner for "day," rather than as a marker of clause subordination (in the terminology of Huddleston & Pullum (2002)). You can add in the marker, yielding a second *that*:

> 2. The fact that it was my forty-sixth birthday should have been my first clue that that day was going to suck.

You could also choose a different determiner to avoid this ambiguity:

> 3. The fact that it was my forty-sixth birthday should have been my first clue the day was going to suck.

This is largely a matter of taste, but I agree that sentences like (1) sound quite bad. At first, it's easy to misinterpret the first "that" as a marker of subordination, making it sound as if "day" is missing a determiner. Adding both instances of "that" avoids that confusion.